# C++ RegGetValue function output error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, registry, windows-10

I am trying to search the registry's uninstall folder for a given program that I know is there by checking regedit.  My function currently finds the program, but for some reason it doesn't update the output value from the RegGetValue function until the next iteration.  So it prints the correct registry key and its predecessor.  Any ideas?

I am on a Windows 10 64bit workstation with Intel processors using Visual Studio 2015 if that matters.

*main.cpp*

```
#include "Registry.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void main()
{
    Registry test(_T("Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client "));
}
```

*Registry.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#define REG_PATH L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"
#define X86REG_PATH L"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"

class Registry
{
public:
    Registry(TCHAR* name);
    ~Registry();
    TCHAR* findGUID();
    TCHAR* getDisplayName();
    TCHAR* getGUID();
    TCHAR* getVersion();
    TCHAR* getPublisher();
    TCHAR* getInstallDate();
private:
    TCHAR* displayName;
    TCHAR* guid;
    TCHAR* version;
    TCHAR* publisher;
    TCHAR* installDate;
};
```

*Registry.cpp*

```
#pragma once

#include "Registry.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>

Registry::Registry(TCHAR* name)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey;
    DWORD ulOptions;
    REGSAM samDesired;

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH, NULL, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::wofstream file;
        file.open("test.txt");
        int index = 0;
        HKEY UninstallDir = hKey;
        TCHAR subKey[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD subKeySize = MAX_PATH;
        while (RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, index, subKey, &subKeySize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            HKEY guid;
            TCHAR* guidPath = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
            _tcscpy_s(guidPath, MAX_PATH, REG_PATH);
            _tcscat_s(guidPath, MAX_PATH, subKey);
            TCHAR compareName[MAX_PATH];
            DWORD nameSize;
            //print all registry keys to file
            file << index << ": " << guidPath << std::endl;
            int test;
            RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, guidPath, _T("DisplayName"), RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, &compareName, &nameSize);
            //compare all registry keys *temporary to debug
            if (_tcscmp(guidPath, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{49D665A2-4C2A-476E-9AB8-FCC425F526FC}")) == 0)
            {
                std::wcout << guidPath << " found" << std::endl;
            }
            if (_tcscmp(compareName, name) == 0)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("%d: %s\n"), index, guidPath);
            }
            //print if found

            index++;
            subKeySize = 260;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open registry key." << std::endl;
    }
    //temporary to see console
    std::cin.get();
}
//still need to be completed   
Registry::~Registry()
{
}

TCHAR* Registry::findGUID()
{
    return _T("");
}

TCHAR* Registry::getDisplayName()
{
    return _T("");
}

TCHAR* Registry::getGUID()
{
    return _T("");
}

TCHAR* Registry::getVersion()
{
    return _T("");
}

TCHAR* Registry::getPublisher()
{
    return _T("");
}

TCHAR* Registry::getInstallDate()
{
    return _T("");
}
```

Comment: `file << index << ": " << guidPath << std::endl;` and `std::wcout << guidPath << " found" << std::endl;` do not output what you think they do. You are mixing `char` and `wchar_t` data. And you are mixing `std::wcout` and `_printf()`, which causes buffering mismatches. And you are leaking `guidPath` on every loop iteration.

Comment: How do I print to debug without leaking the path?

Comment: You have to `delete []` anything you allocate with `new []`. Otherwise, use `std::vector` or `std::basic_string` instead. Also, you should be using `std::wcout` instead of `_printf()`. And you should not being `X86REG_PATH` at all, use the `RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6432KEY` flag instead.

Comment: I didn't know about the registry subkeys being defined.  l so I will definitely use them, and I knew to delete a heap object; I am just caught on my bug. This issue with the logic right now is when i debug after finding the first instance of the key, the reason I put the first if statement in, the next iteratation doesn't update the compareName field and will print the next guidPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a lot of problems with your code.

You are mixing `std::wcout` and `_tprintf()`, which causes buffering conflicts.

You are mixing `char` and `wchar_t` data incorrectly.

You are leaking `guidPath` on every loop iteration.

You are not initializing `nameSize` when calling `RegGetValue()`.

You are not setting up your code to access the 32bit `Wow64Node` key correctly.

Try something more like this instead.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Registry.h"

void main()
{
    Registry test(L"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client");
}
```

*Registry.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Registry
{
public:
    Registry(const std::wstring &name);
    ~Registry();
    std::wstring findGUID();
    std::wstring getDisplayName();
    std::wstring getGUID();
    std::wstring getVersion();
    std::wstring getPublisher();
    std::wstring getInstallDate();
private:
    std::wstring displayName;
    std::wstring guid;
    std::wstring version;
    std::wstring publisher;
    std::wstring installDate;
};
```

*Registry.cpp*

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include "Registry.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define REG_PATH L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"

Registry::Registry(const std::wstring &name)
{
    HKEY hKey;

    // If you want to open the 32bit Wow64Node key,
    // DO NOT open the key directly! Open the 64bit
    // key and include the KEY_WOW64_32KEY flag
    // so it will redirect to the Wow64Node key...
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH, NULL, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::wofstream file;
        file.open(L"test.txt");

        WCHAR subKey[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD subKeySize = MAX_PATH;
        WCHAR compareName[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD nameSize;
        int index = 0;

        while (RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, index, subKey, &subKeySize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            // print all registry keys to file
            file << index << L": " << REG_PATH << subKey << std::endl;
            int test;
            nameSize = sizeof(compareName);
            RegGetValue(hKey, NULL, L"DisplayName", RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ | RRF_ZEROONFAILURE, NULL, compareName, &nameSize);
            //compare all registry keys *temporary to debug
            if (wcscmp(subKey, L"{49D665A2-4C2A-476E-9AB8-FCC425F526FC}") == 0)
            {
                std::wcout << subKey << L" found" << std::endl;
            }
            if (name == compareName)
            {
                std::wcout << name << L" found" << std::endl;
            }
            //print if found

            index++;
            subKeySize = MAX_PATH;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << L"Could not open registry key." << std::endl;
    }

    //temporary to see console
    std::wcin.get();
}

//still need to be completed   
Registry::~Registry()
{
}

std::wstring Registry::findGUID()
{
    return L"";
}

std::wstring Registry::getDisplayName()
{
    return L"";
}

std::wstring Registry::getGUID()
{
    return L"";
}

std::wstring Registry::getVersion()
{
    return L"";
}

std::wstring Registry::getPublisher()
{
    return L"";
}

std::wstring Registry::getInstallDate()
{
    return L"";
}
```

Comment: Okay. Will try tomorrow at work.  Is there any good documentation you recommend to read?  I have no experience with the windows defined types and am just practicing for learning purposes.

Comment: Also, why the explicit use of wchar functions vs _tchar functions?

Comment: Your solution worked. The problem I had was not resetting the nameSize value to the max length it could see.  Thank you.

Comment: @TravisCook `TCHAR` is meant to be used for backwards compatibility with legacy code that targets Win9x/ME and NT4+ in a single codebase. Nobody supports Win9x/ME anymore. Windows NT4+ is all Unicode, you should use Unicode APIs only. Don't use ANSI APIs unless you really need to.

Comment: My employeer said to use TCHAR for all C++ code in place of wchar and char due to compatibility of their products. But I don't think we suppose below XP so I will ask about it.  Thanks for input.